# What are non-variance (non Markowitz) based theories of capital allocation between non-correlated assets?

Tags: risk, portfolio-optimization, correlation, asset-allocation

A large amount of literature in finance accepts the standard deviation in return as if it were an accurate measure of "risk."

What are some other financial theories for how to allocate capital between assets that are not correlated? What principles would lead to an equal, cagr, or some other weighting?

Using sigma is arbitrary and also 70 years old. Are there other models for how to allocate between non-correlated assets?

Answer (score 1):

Risk Budgeting, to which Risk Parity is closely related.

Related to that: [Risk Parity / Equal Risk Contribution with Tail Risk Measures](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/40340/risk-parity-equal-risk-contribution-with-tail-risk-measures?rq=1)

Comment: Any quantification of risk based on the variance of a distribution has the same form as the CAPM. I'm looking for allocation schemes which do not assume such a parameter.

Comment: @Machinus this is semantics, but imo risk parity does not have the same form as capm.  i agree that it uses volatility as an input, but that's because the volatility matters.  maybe i just don't understand your question, or maybe this is me just saying that i don't have an answer for you, or that sigma is absolutely not arbitrary.  watch this from dalio on his holy grail of investing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nu4lHaSh7D4  you could argue that and say future estimates of sigma and the correlations are arbitrary.  to that i would say we just do the best we can?  hopefully this helps?

Comment: anyway this topic really interests me because over the years i haven't found anything better so please let me know what you think of that.  i too yearn for something different.

Comment: Sigma is an artificial proxy for risk used in quantitative finance, but it does not actually measure risk. Over long time periods, volatility does not matter for returns. CAGR contains all of the information about the returns of an asset. 

Risk parity uses sigma so it is just a different calibration of the same risk proxy. I am looking for an allocation model that does not use standard deviation.

Comment: A method which uses only past returns is the Universal Portfolios of Thomas M. Cover. But not widely used in practice AFAIK, more of a theoretical construct.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because there's something I'm not sure about w.r.t. the volatility drag coefficient I mentioned.  I'll report back if I confirm it.  Anyway, this is interesting!

Comment: Universal Portfolios is really interesting.  I ran some sims to compare portfolios suggested by the UP and more classical methods.  Machinus, you could take your CAGRs and specify different distributions of returns for the underlyings, assuming they still fit with your CAGR, and then use simulation with this UP method.  I don't think you'll be happy with that but I wanted to circle back.  Thanks everyone for the intellectual stimulation!